# Masking on Image in augmented reality

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am using Example occlusion management in android, in which masking is applied when camera comes to the target.
But I want to apply masking on image  when camera move in, and unmasking when camera move out.

Hope you understand what I'm trying to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Experts of QualComm VUforia Augmented Reality says that this can`t be achive with the native Sdk for these we need to use Unity 3D  as this is the concept of Depth masking and not possible for the native SDK